# How to print XML tag names along with their values in shell script

Tags: xml, shell, sed, xml-parsing, tags

I have a sample `pom.xml`. I need to print particular XML tags with their values to another XML. I am able to extract the values of the tags, but I am not able to print along the tag names.

XML code:

```
<dependency>
<job>xmlparsing</job>
<version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Command used:**

```
sed -ne '/<\/job>/ { s/<[^>]*>\(.*\)<\/job>/\1/; p }
```

**Actual output:**

```
xmlparsing
```

**Expected output:**

```
<job>xmlparsing</job>
```

How can I modify the sed command to print the XML tags with their values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can install and use xmlstarlet, this would be the preferred way:

```
 xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//dependency/job' pom.xml
```

notice the use of `-c` instead of `-v`

---

if you have to use `sed` replacing `\1` (the content of what was matched inside the first `\(` `\)` pair) by `\0` (the content that was matched by the entire regex) should do the trick, but it is not good to parse xml with regular expressions:

```
sed -ne '/<\/job>/ { s/<[^>]*>\(.*\)<\/job>/\0/; p }
```